# How do I prevent an int from becoming negative after subtracting

Tags: c#, winforms, math, boolean-logic

I am trying to subtract a value from an `int` which has a set value.  Once it gets to 0 and I subtract more from it, the value becomes negative.

I thought if I used an `if-else` statement to check whether the value goes below 0 it would prevent the value from becoming negative.  But the value proceeds into the negative.  How do I prevent the value from going into the negative range?

```
        {
            DateTime start = dateTimePicker2.Value.Date;
            DateTime end = dateTimePicker1.Value.Date;

            TimeSpan difference = end - start;

            int days = difference.Days;
            int min = 0;
            int max = 21;
            int rdays = Convert.ToInt32(Holidays_Number_lbl.Text);
            Holidays_Number_lbl.Text = (rdays - days).ToString();

            int Holidays_Number = int.Parse(Holidays_Number_lbl.Text);
            if ((Holidays_Number > min)  && (Holidays_Number < max))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Holidays have been counted");
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show(" You have exceeded your 21 holidays  ");//value goes into the minus ?
            }
        }
```

Expected result:  MessageBox appears saying you have exceeded your days and value doesn't go into the negative.

Actual Result: Value proceeds into the negative.

Comment: you can check if it goes below 0 and display a messagebox, but you also need to set it to 0. if(val < 0){ val = 0;}

Comment: `Holidays_Number_lbl.Text = Math.Max(0, rdays - days).ToString();`  Only convert things into strings when you need to display them.

Comment: You are checking the value after setting it, so it is negative when you check it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify zero as the lowest possible value with `Math.Max()`on the line where you do the arithmetic:

```
Holidays_Number_lbl.Text = (Math.Max(rdays - days, 0)).ToString();
```

However, you're converting to a string and then back to a number.  Something like this would eliminate the need for `int.Parse`:

```
...

 int Holidays_Number = Math.Max(rdays - days, 0);
 Holidays_Number_lbl.Text = Holidays_Number.ToString();
 if ((Holidays_Number > min)  && (Holidays_Number < max))
 {

...
```

Answer (score 1):

This line `int Holidays_Number = int.Parse(Holidays_Number_lbl.Text);` is setting the value of `Holidays_Number`. Then the next line checks that with an `if` statement. But the `if` statement does not change the value, it just checks it. So if it is below 0, it will remain below 0.